# How to set sgLevel parameter when loading tsfile after exporting tsfile in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I exported the tsfile, and tried to load this tsfile again in Apache IoTDB. Seems like I got an error message that prompted my sgLevel setting. I set sgLevel to be true, and the error message is: mismatched input 'true' expecting INTEGER_LITERAL. Can anyone suggest how to set this sgLevel parameter to successfully load tsfile?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `SGLEVEL` option should be set to a definite number in Apache IoTDB.

`SGLEVEL` represents the level of this database when the database corresponding to certain TsFile does not exist. The default value of `SGLEVEL` should be the level set in `iotdb-datanode.properties`.

For example, setting `SGLEVEL` to 1 indicates that the prefix path with level 1 in all time series in this TsFile is the database, that is, if there is a device `root.sg.d1.s1`, then `root.sg` is designated as database.